# Create a range or array of integers up to a total int number

Tags: arrays, swift

I want to be able to convert a whole int to an array of elements. So If the int is 4 I want to be able to convert it to an array with 4 elements. Like so:

```
var num = 4

var arr = [1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: It not quite understand the question? if how to make this transformation - the elementary cycle from 1 to a value with add current element to array but you mean something else?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: I mean for var i=1; i<= num; ++i {arr.append(i)}

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use an Int's array initializer with a range.

Either:

```
let arr = [Int](1...4)
```

or:

```
let arr = Array(1...4)
```

Result:

> [1, 2, 3, 4]

```
let num = 4

let arr = Array(1...num)
```