# How to create an array with incremented values in Swift?

Tags: swift

I know that I can create an array with repeated values in Swift with:

```
var myArray = [Int](count: 5, repeatedValue: 0)
```

But is there a way to create an array with incremented values such as `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` other than to do a loop such as

```
var myArray = [Int]()
for i in 0 ... 4 {
    myArray.append(i)
}
```

I know that code is pretty straightforward, readable, and bulletproof, but it *feels* like I should be able pass some function in some way to the array as it's created to provided the incremented values. It might not be worth the cost in readability or computationally more efficient, but I'm curious nonetheless.

Comment: @vacawama, the reason that I missed it was the "filled" in the title of the post didn't suggest to me that the contents of the array would be some iterated function. Perhaps just my own lack of imagination. Certainly the answer is the same. I still appreciate those who answered my question, as I had searched before asking.

Comment: I can see that it might have been difficult to find.  I updated the title of the duplicate to add "a range" to make it easier to find in the future.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33245447/2303865

Comment: 2 days ago http://stackoverflow.com/a/34551270/2303865

Comment: @LeoDabus, immediately when I saw that a range is an object (and its values explicitly available,) I recognized the possibilities. Stride is really cool: thanks for alerting me to its existence.

Answer (score 281, accepted):

Use the `...` notation / operator:

```
let arr1 = 0...4
```

That gets you a `Range`, which you can easily turn into a "regular" `Array`:

```
let arr2 = Array(0...4)
```

Comment: How would you initialize an array of `Double`s?

Comment: @Adrian use the `stride(from:to:by:)`function (or `stride(from:through:by:)`) for Double's. Ex: `let myArray = Array(stride(from: 0.0, through: 5.0, by: 1.0))` gives you an Array of Double's : `[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]`.

Comment: You can also do: `let indices: [Int] = (0..<4).indices.map { $0 } // 0,1,2,3`

Comment: to add to the topic, if you need to repeat a call to a function with a set of parameters you can do 
`let datas = Array(0...4).compactMap { firstAttribute.repeatedFunc(param: $0) }`

you can think of 0...4 as your known params, it could be ["Mr", "Mrs", "X"]