# Create an array where the values are not the same as the previous value

Tags: arrays, swift, algorithm

How do I create an array of Integer values where one value is not the same as the previous value?

Like this:

```
var arrayOfNumbers = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Or like this:

```
var arrayOfNumbers = [1,4,2,5,3]
```

But not like this:

```
var arrayOfNumbers = [1,2,2,4,5]
```

Guess I should study algo's a little better but thankful for any help so I know here to start! :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create an array with incremented values in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571043/how-to-create-an-array-with-incremented-values-in-swift)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the collection type `Set` which guarantees unique values.

```
var uniqueValues = Set<Int>()

uniqueValues.insert(newInt) // will do nothing if value exists
```

Elements of a `Set` are not ordered.

If you want to keep the order, use `Array` but check before you insert.

```
if !uniqueValues.contains(1) { uniqueValues.append(1) }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func getUniqueArray(elementCount:Int,range:Range<Int>)->[Int] {
    var numArray:[Int] = []
    while numArray.count < elementCount {
        let num = Int.random(in: range)
        if !numArray.contains(num) {
            numArray.append(num)
        }
    }
    return numArray
}


print(getUniqueArray(elementCount: 5, range: 0..<100))
```

Answer (score 0):

@dilan-anuruddha answers should do it, just in case you already have the array and you want the distinct ones (And you don't want to use set (that should be the best approach))

```
func distinc(_ array:[Int]){
    var distinc:[Int] = []
    array.each {
        guard !distinct.contains($0) else { continue }
        distinct.append($0)
    }
    return distinc
}
```